# Problema ao criar segurança SQL INJECTION

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

> Tenho uma função PHP onde passo os dados para ela e a mesma da um UPDATE nos dados. porém estou fazendo segurança contra SQL INJECTION, só que não está funcionando qual seria o problema? Segue o código da função:

```
function alterar($upd_tabela, $upd_condicao, $upd_dados){
# Armazenas os dados do array
$upd_campos = array_keys($upd_dados);
# contagem dos campos existentes
$upd_n_campos = count($upd_dados);
//Armazena as condicoes existentes que serão inseridas no WHERE 
$upd_campos_condicao = array_keys($upd_condicao);
//conta quantas condições são existentes
$upd_n_condicao = count($upd_condicao);
// Inicia a sintaxe 
$upd_sintaxe = "UPDATE ".$upd_tabela." SET "; 
//monta o resto da estrutura 
for($upd_aux=0; $upd_aux<$upd_n_campos; $upd_aux++){
    $upd_sintaxe.= $upd_campos[$upd_aux]."=".$upd_campos[$upd_aux].", "; 
}
//retira a ultima virgula 
$upd_sintaxe = substr($upd_sintaxe, 0, -2);
//abre o WHERE 
$upd_sintaxe.= " WHERE ";
//adiciona as condições  
for($upd_aux=0; $upd_aux<$upd_n_condicao; $upd_aux++){
    $upd_sintaxe.= $upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]."=".$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]." ";
}
//chama a função global para fazer conexão com o Banco de dados
global $conexaobd;
//prepara a sintaxe 
$upd_preparado = $conexaobd->prepare($upd_sintaxe);
//sera os valores de cada campo 
for($upd_aux=0; $upd_aux<$upd_n_campos; $upd_aux++){
    if(!$upd_dados[$upd_campos[$upd_aux]]){
        echo $upd_dados[$upd_campos[$upd_aux]] = NULL;
    }
    $upd_preparado -> bindParam(":".$upd_campos[$upd_aux], $upd_dados[$upd_campos[$upd_aux]]);
}
//seta os valores de cada condição
for($upd_aux=0; $upd_aux<$upd_n_condicao; $upd_aux++){
    if(!$upd_condicao[$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]]){
        echo $upd_condicao[$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]] = NULL;
    }
    $upd_preparado -> bindParam(":".$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux], $upd_condicao[$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]]);
}
//executa e retorna o UPDATE
return $upd_preparado->execute();
//Para debugar o código
$upd_preparado->debugDumpParams();
```

}

> OBS.: Ao dar um echo na sintaxe, aparece o seguinte: **SQL: [44] UPDATE categorias SET nome=nome WHERE id=id**
>
> ```
> Params: 2 Key: Name: [5] :nome paramno=-1 name=[5] ":nome" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [3] :id paramno=-1 name=[3] ":id" is_param=1 param_type=2'
> ```

Comment: Com `prepare` o `update` normalmente tem o seguinte aspeto : `update tabela set campo1=?, campo2=?...`

Comment: Em que momento você aplica a validação do _SQL INJECTION_? O trecho de código que postou apenas monta a _query_.

Comment: Leia: [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864)

Comment: @DjalmaManfrin estou primeiramente refazendo minhas funções, depois irei trabalhar com as validações

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro que você leia mais sobre [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Tente mudar isto

```
$upd_sintaxe.= $upd_campos[$upd_aux].":".$upd_campos[$upd_aux].", ";
```

para

```
$upd_sintaxe.= $upd_campos[$upd_aux]."= :".$upd_campos[$upd_aux].", ";
```

Assim ficaria o código completo:

```
function alterar($upd_tabela, $upd_condicao, $upd_dados){
# Armazenas os dados do array
$upd_campos = array_keys($upd_dados);
# contagem dos campos existentes
$upd_n_campos = count($upd_dados);
//Armazena as condicoes existentes que serão inseridas no WHERE 
$upd_campos_condicao = array_keys($upd_condicao);
//conta quantas condições são existentes
$upd_n_condicao = count($upd_condicao);
// Inicia a sintaxe 
$upd_sintaxe = "UPDATE ".$upd_tabela." SET "; 
//monta o resto da estrutura 
for($upd_aux=0; $upd_aux<$upd_n_campos; $upd_aux++){
    $upd_sintaxe.= $upd_campos[$upd_aux]."= :".$upd_campos[$upd_aux].", "; 
}
//retira a ultima virgula 
$upd_sintaxe = substr($upd_sintaxe, 0, -2);

//abre o WHERE 
$upd_sintaxe.= " WHERE ";
//adiciona as condições  
for($upd_aux=0; $upd_aux<$upd_n_condicao; $upd_aux++){
    $upd_sintaxe.= $upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]."= :".$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]." ";
}
//chama a função global para fazer conexão com o Banco de dados
global $conexaobd;
//prepara a sintaxe 
$upd_preparado = $conexaobd->prepare($upd_sintaxe);
//sera os valores de cada campo 
for($upd_aux=0; $upd_aux<$upd_n_campos; $upd_aux++){
    if(!$upd_dados[$upd_campos[$upd_aux]]){
        echo $upd_dados[$upd_campos[$upd_aux]] = NULL;
    }
    $upd_preparado -> bindParam(":".$upd_campos[$upd_aux], $upd_dados[$upd_campos[$upd_aux]]);
}
//seta os valores de cada condição
for($upd_aux=0; $upd_aux<$upd_n_condicao; $upd_aux++){
    if(!$upd_condicao[$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]]){
        echo $upd_condicao[$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]] = NULL;
    }
    $upd_preparado -> bindParam(":".$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux], $upd_condicao[$upd_campos_condicao[$upd_aux]]);
}
//executa e retorna o UPDATE
 return $upd_preparado->execute();
//Para debugar o código
 //$upd_preparado->debugDumpParams();
```

}

Aqui tem link da sintaxe [SET MYSQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Comment: humm, é que no insert eu faço com : e fica assim:
  `$adc_sintaxe.= ":".$adc_campos[$adc_aux].", ";`

Comment: e funcionar perfeitamente, é normal isso?

Comment: voce devia organizar mais seu codigo,use normas, está uma bagunça, reveja os links que citei

Comment: Certo dei uma lida, fiz a sua alteração mas não ocorre o UPDATE, acho que tem algum erro na parte de setar o valor, atualizei o código

Comment: mano na verdade o ":" fica no código junto com o "=", obrigado pela sua ajuda! agora está funcionando.